# How can I answer the "scan another CD" prompt during Debian install with preseed?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, kickstart, preseed

I've got a preseeded install from cdrom working smoothly, except for ONE prompt. It does the scan of the cdrom before installing software, and asks me if I want to insert an additional CD to scan.

Is there any way to force this question to be answered no with preseed?

This is with a 7.5.0-wheezy installed solely from CD1.

Updated 6/11/2014: Wound up just switching to the netinstall instead of from CD, so don't actually know if the below answer worked, but I've accepted it since it looks like the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `debconf-get-selections --installer` output includes this:

```
# Scan another CD or DVD?
apt-cdrom-setup apt-setup/cdrom/set-next    boolean false
```

That's from Ubuntu, but it's probably appropriate for you too.

Comment: I'm not sure if you want `false` or `true` though.

Answer (score 10):

I attempted bburky's fix, but found that the following was needed in Debian Wheezy...

```
d-i apt-setup/use_mirror boolean false
d-i apt-setup/cdrom/set-first boolean false
d-i apt-setup/cdrom/set-next boolean false   
d-i apt-setup/cdrom/set-failed boolean false
```